# How to Serialize unserializable object in .NET

Tags: c#

I have 3-rd party dll. From that I receive an object of some type (I know its interface, but not all the object). That object is not marked as serializable and I'm not related to that libruary development at all.

I want to serialize it to some storage and then receive it from storage with **the same state later (public/private, references etc.)**. I got here one option - make my own serialization mechanism that will act the same as .NET serializers with the only difference - it won't revise serialization attributes.

Is that the best way?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the XmlSerializer serializes everything?

Comment: No. Only objects marked with serializable attributes.

Comment: XmlSerializer is very restricted. For example it doesn't support cyclic object graphs.

Comment: What kind of serializer do you want? Properties or fields? Do you need cyclic graphs or polymorphism?

Comment: @LexRema, what you are saying about serializable attributes and XmlSerializer is wrong. Attributes are there to customize the process but aren't required at all. Take a POCO and feed it to a XmlSerializer instance. It works. Of course there are some caveats with stuff like recursive objects and Streams but workarounds could be found. I think that you need to provide more information about the object you are trying to serialize.

Comment: I want to abstragate from that, so let's say an object graph.

Comment: If you even need to serialize private fields, then this is properbly a bad way to go. What i would do is to make a state object, where you set all the properties and methods though that. It then records the values, and you can then serialize that object, and tell it to do all the actions again, when you load it.

Comment: @Lex - Create a wrapper class that is serialized.  Of course this also depends on how you are going to place it in storage ( I am not exactly sure what that means ).

Comment: @ Barfieldmv It does serialize public properties/fields without marking object serializable. But not deeper.

Comment: @LexRema, I repeat you once again that what you are saying is not true. Here's a code snippet I wrote to illustrate: http://snipt.org/wkpnh. Try it and you will see how nicely nested complex properties are serialized. And you can have any nesting level you like. And without any attributes. So?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, did you try adding any non-public field/property? I did. And that is where this story ends.

Comment: @LexRema, you should have mentioned that you are trying to serialize private properties in your question. I can't see any such information. That's why I asked you to show the object you are trying to serialize. Because there is no serialization method that will work in all cases. Depending on what you are trying to serialize there might be different techniques. Don't get me wrong: I am trying to help but without you providing more details about your scenario I doubt you will get a good answer.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Ok. I thought **the same state later** is clear, but now have aded some edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) or [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) to serialize types not marked with `SerializableAttribute`.

There may be other options. And can always go ahead with custom implementation if nothing works for you.

Comment: I've only public contract of the object, so seems it's not the option without using reflection.

Comment: Not all types are serializable with `XmlSerializer` - for instance the `Dictionary<>` type.

Comment: @Phil, yes, that's why we need to see what object the OP is working with. Otherwise answers stay abstract and cannot be targeted in way to choose the best solution in the OPs scenario.

Comment: @Phil: Actually, to be clear, `generics` are not supported. I am aware of that. That is why I put the last statement there.

Comment: It does serialize public properties/fields without marking object serializable. But not deeper.

Comment: To serialize a type with XML you need a `[XmlRoot]` attribute, I guess.

Comment: @Vercas: No, that is not mandatory. But, provides more customization.

Comment: @decyclone Ah, okay. It's just that it never worked for me without that attribute...

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own class inheriting from that object and serialize it.
OR you can make your own replica of that class and make some explicit (or implicit, but not recommended) conversion methods.

Comment: I have only interface and need to serialize their inherited object. I don't know what object thay use and have no opportunity to inherit it.

Comment: `MyObj.GetType()` might help you get some clues.

Comment: GetType () for runtime inheriting? That might be cool :). But I'll need to do the same with all referenced objects, that makes the task impossible :)

Comment: @LexRama Well, the only way you are going to achieve this is to recursively dissect the object types and insert the values in a Dictionary<object, object> which can be serialized.